Disabling RPI media output
when I connecting to my RPI via bluetooth it detect it like headphones and think that it have media output. I want to disable it  .

here you can see that it appears in the media output of the phone. I don't want it to appear in the media output of the phone.
i tried to change the class but it doesn't worked
pleas help me i am stuck on in for hours

Have you tried to disable audio services altogether?

You can see what Bluetooth profiles your RPi machine supports by doing bluetoothctl show. You should get out that includes something similar to:
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

When the Bluetooth daemon (bluetoothd) is started it can be configured with what profiles it supports.
man bluetoothd will give you more information. The key bit is to change what plugins are included or excluded.

   -p, --plugin=<plugin1>,<plugin2>,..
          Load these plugins only. The option can be a pattern containing  "*" and "?" characters.

   -P, --noplugin=<plugin1>,<plugin2>,..
          Never load these plugins. The option can be a pattern containing "*" and "?"  characters.


You can see details of the Bluetooth service by doing the following command:
systemctl status bluetooth.service

To change how the daemon is started on your system you have to edit the following file:
/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service

The line that starts the daemon is:
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

So you would add --noplugin=a2dp to disable the audio services.
The complete list of plugins are:

builtin
hostname
wiimote
autopair
policy
neard
sap
a2dp
avrcp
network
input
hog
health
gap
scanparam
deviceinfo
midi
battery

Once you have edited the file you will need to reload the file and restart the service. You can reboot or do the following:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service

bluetoothctl show and systemctl status bluetooth.service should show you if you have been successful.
